# Mathematica arbitrary number of graphics

Tags: loops, graphics, wolfram-mathematica, show

I am new to Mathematica 10.2 and am attempting to put multiple objects in a single graphic. This wouldn't be much of a problem if the number of objects were fixed. The following code gives the exact result that I am looking for, but it is not general enough:

```
p = f[a]

Out[797]= {{4, 5, 11, 774.79}, {2, 7, 10, 1161.3}, {3, 8, 12, 1772.8}, {1, 6, 9, 2900.6}}

For[i = 1, i <= m, i++, 
  plot[i] = 
    Graphics[{Line[{data[[p[[i, 1]]]], data[[p[[i, 2]]]]}], 
    Line[{data[[p[[i, 2]]]], data[[p[[i, 3]]]]}], 
    Line[{data[[p[[i, 1]]]], data[[p[[i, 3]]]]}]}]]

Show[plot[1], plot[2], plot[3], plot[4]]
```

For clarity, the first three numbers in each element of *p* refer to the index of the data set *data*, which contain ordered pairs. The fourth number is perimeter.

The last line generates a graphic of four triangles. The problem is that *p* could have any number of elements, and I need this to generate any number of triangles. I've tried to use *Do* and *For* loops through the plot list I crated within the *Show* command, but that doesn't work. Is there a command that I'm missing, or is there a more direct method of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Since nobody reading this, except you, knows what your f or your data or your preceeding 797 lines are it is very difficult to guess how to answer. Is there any chance you could adapt this? numberOfTriangles = 5; verticies = RandomReal[{0, 6}, {numberOfTriangles, 3, 2}] closed = Map[Join[#, {First[#]}] &, verticies] Show[Graphics[Line[closed]]] If not then could you perhaps create a simple self contained example that would others would be able to know everything involved and just complicated enough that whatever answer they gave would be enough for you to solve your problem?

Comment: Probably better asked at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com  But if you do ask there be prepared to explain what you are trying to do.  In Mathematica there is almost always a better way to do anything that a newcomer to the system (especially one coming from imperative programming languages such as C or Java) would start writing with `For`.

Comment: `Show[Table[plot[i],{i,4}]`.  Better still use  `Table` instead of the `For` loop in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion; there aren't actually 796 lines before, I'd just evaluated that many lines throughout my session while working on it without clearing. Anyway, what agentp suggested was tremendously helpful; I knew there was a concise command that would do what I was doing, I just didn't know about the Table function. Thank you